# while(getline(myReadFile, temp, ':')) executing one iteration too many causing out of bounds on vector

Tags: c++, readline, readfile

I have a question on std::readline(istream, string, delimiter). I am trying to read in a file and store the data in a struct and add it to a map. That I have gotten to work. However my while loop iterates one loop too many causing my vector to have no data stored in it which causes an assertion failure for out of bounds.

I have read every stack overflow question on readline and none seem to give me any idea as to why this behavior occurs.  Perhaps someone here can enlighten me.

```
if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
    while(getline(myReadFile, temp, ':')){//loops through and splits the line one delimiter at a time
        stringVector.push_back(temp);//add to vector
        ItemInfo tempItem = ItemInfo(stringVector[1], stod(stringVector[2]), stod(stringVector[3]));//create the struct
        catalog.insert(pair<string,ItemInfo>(stringVector[0], tempItem));//add to map
        stringVector.clear();
    }

}

    myReadFile.close();
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: When you call `ItemInfo(stringVector[1], stod(stringVector[2]), stod(stringVector[3]))` does the vector have 3 elements in it?

Comment: What exactly do you think that `getline` call does?

Comment: The vector contains one element, and you're trying to access its second, third and fourth elements. That is very unlikely to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present code should break at first iteration.

Assuming you strart with an empty vection, you read first line of file in `tmp`, fine. Then you push_back tmp into your vector, still fine. Vector contains exactly one element of index 0.

But on next line you try to use elements of index 1, 2 and 3 from the vector that contains only one element => index out of bound exception guaranteed.